# How to solve this Swift problem (AP CP Principles - Structures)

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct

I am currently going through Apple Curriculum books and stumbled across a problem I can't figure out.

There is a structure:

```
struct Song {
    let title: String
    let artist: String
    let duration: Int
    var longestSong = false 
}
```

and an array with 4 songs that have different duration: 90, 200, 150, 440.

The book asks to add a method that checks whether one song is longer than the other.

So, based on previous material I added the following method to my struct:

```
func isLongerThan(_ song: Song) -> Bool {
     return duration > song.duration
     }
}
```

Then the book asks to use a loop in order to find the longest song in the array and print it to the console

> (Hint: use a variable to keep track of the longest song and initialize
> it to the first one in the array.)

So, I came up with this loop:

```
for (index, _) in songs.enumerated() {
    if index < songs.count-1{
        if songs[index].isLongerThan(songs[index + 1]){
            songs[index].longestSong = true
            print("\(songs[index].title) is longer than \(songs[index+1].title)")
            }
    } else {
        if songs[songs.count-1].isLongerThan(songs[0]){
            songs[songs.count-1].longestSong = true
            print("\(songs[songs.count-1].title) is longer than \(songs[0].title)")
        }
    }
}
```

The next step is to compare those songs with longestSong = true variable until only one song remains. But this isn't a good solution in my opinion.

Is there a better and more elegant way to solve this problem?

UPD
It seems that I have misread the instructions and have gone the wrong way.
With some help I managed to find this solution:

```
func searchForLongestSong(songs: [Song]) {
    var lngstSongIndex = 0

    for song in 0..<songs.count {
        if songs[song].duration > songs[lngstSongIndex].duration {
            lngstSongIndex = song
        }
    }
    print("The longst song is \"\(songs[lngstSongIndex].title)\"")
}

searchForLongestSong(songs: songs)
```

Comment: You are supposed to use a variable to keep track of the longest song but you have instead created a property `longest` so revert back to use a variable instead. `var longest = songs[0]` and then use a basic for loop with a range

Comment: A comment on your update, since you are only using the variable `lngstSongIndex` inside the function `searchForLongestSong` it should be declared inside that function. Always declare your variables in the scope you are using them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an `Array` you can keep track of the "longest song" by saving the index of the longest song.

Create an `Int` `var` to save the index.

Loop through the indices `for n in 0..<songs.count`

if the `duration` of `songs[n]` is greater than `songs[largestSongIdx]`

Then update the `longestSong` variables for both accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now this problem looks very simple.

Comment: It usually is. What book are you reading?

Comment: "Develop in Swift AP CS Principles" which is part of the official Apple Curriculum (it consists of 3 books). They updated it earlier this year. You can find this book in the Books app for free.